Reactjs 'Wildcard' in Router
I have the following route established:
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(<>
    <Route path={`/:siteid/login`} element={< LoginLayout/>}>       
<>)

Of course /test/login works well, but I want to use the same route for /test/again/login   Is there a way to get the route to work for both URLs without creating a different route path.
Using the latest version of react-router-dom
Thanks

Here the the documentation that can help with this:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#optional-segments
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats

So something like  <Route path={/:siteid/:route?/login} element={< LoginLayout/>}> ?

Nope, in previous versions path could accept an array of 'aliases'. Unfortunately that doesn't exist anymore, you'll have to do it yourself. If you have a lot of aliases, consider creating a array with a loop, and then pass that to createBrowserRouter.

But it seems like you're trying to add a 'optional segment', which you can capture using ?:
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(<>
    <Route path={`/:siteid/:optional?/login`} element={< LoginLayout/>}>       
<>)

Should match both your routes.
